# Changing the user ID and file ownerships while there are processes running

Tags: ubuntu

I wrote a bash script to iterate over the /etc/passwd and change each UID to a new value as provided by an input file of name-UID values. As an additional caution, I wrote in a check if there are running processes:

```
# Mod user and group
  usermod -u $uid $login
  groupmod -g $uid $login
  find /data -group $old_uid -exec chgrp -h $login {} \;
  find /data -user $old_gid -exec chown -h $login {} \;
```

Unfortunately, it turns out that most users have some processes even when they are not actively using the machine.
How dangerous would it be executing the above code while there are processes running?

Comment: Probably depends on your definition of "_dangerous_". Tools like `usermod` may have a built-in restriction that prevents them changing anything if the UID is in use

Comment: @roaima I read that comment as, `usermod` might have a safety catch preventing you shooting yourself in the foot.  If it doesn't then, well, byby foot.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I believe so, yes, but I'm not in a position you be able to test right now

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty dangerous operation.  IF YOU MUST do this, then do everything in your power ensure nothing is running for those users.

- Tell the users (with as much warning as possible) what you're doing and when you are doing it.
- Ask them politely to kill any running processes they have before you start your work.
- Temporarily prevent all users from logging while you work
- forcibly kill all user processes and sessions before you begin

**And here's why ...**. for the sake of this discussion `usermod` and `groupmod` only affect:

- The UID, GID and groups the user session is assigned when the user logs-in
- The lookup used for operations like `chgrp` or `sudo`
- the reverse lookup used by things like `ls -l`

All running processes will have exactly the same UID and GID they always did.  This is really bad if you change a user while they have something running:

- Any old login sessions they still have open will hold the old UID and GID.  If you recycle the UID and GID they will effectively be logged in as another user.
- Any processes they had running which are not attached to a current login session will effectively go "rogue".  The user will no longer be able to login and kill them, there may no longer be any user who can other than `root`
- As you are changing file ownership as well, any running processes may simply crash out anyway when they lose all access to the data they were processing.